# python GUI frameworks / libraries suited for data analysis programs

Tags: python, user-interface, traits, enthought

I'm looking for a good cross platform (mac, windows & linux) python GUI framework / library that will make my life easier while writing a data analysis program. Since my data is represented by custom data classes, it would be great if the GUI framework / library could take away the burden of having to code input checks, validation, etc (i.e., create input dialogs that take care of checking for the correct data range / data type based on the data model). The only library that I've found so far is **TraitsUI**. Are there more (similar) libraries / frameworks out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then Enthought Suite (not just TraitsUI) is the most complete as it provides everything from building the model to showing it including input validation. It  plays nicely with numpy and scipy which is nice for a scientific app. Enthought UI can use Qt (via PySide or PyQt) or wx as backends.

You can also use Qt directly via PyQt or Pyside and embed plots using matplotlib or PyQwt. QtDesigner allows you to generate nice UI with very little effort. You can achieve the type of initialization, validation as with Traits but with more effort.

Comment: is it also possible to use QtDesigner to build the GUI of the main program and use Enthought Suite for the data model GUI parts?

Comment: @memyself: I have actually asked the same recently in enthought-dev mail list but I have not received any answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://qt.nokia.com/products/

Comment: are there any advantages / disadvantages using QT compared to Traits?

Comment: these packages can't be compared. QT is a library independent of Python, but with an existing Python interface to manage windows/frames and their content.
Traits is much more specialized, e.g. Traits alone is bringing back static typing to Python and nice management of properties (attribute-dependencies etc.) while only traits.ui is a GUI library on top. I would strongly encourage any scientist who needs to create data analysis apps to try Traits and Traits.UI because it's very amazing how much can be done in only one day with these powerful libraries. (I have no affiliation, just a big fan.)

Comment: sorry, too hasty down vote. But I do dislike how lazy it seems to be given...

Answer (score 0):

When you said "Python", do you mean Python  as a "language"  irrespective of implementation (i.e. CPython)? If I take this question assuming "Python as a language, and I need a cross platform features, I would probably use Jython (Python on Java) that has  good integration with Java Swift, thus our program should work on many different platforms. You may look at the GUI examples implemented in Jython in the [DataMelt project](https://jwork.org/dmelt/code/index.php?art=GUI/Swing)